# Storage gateway reset cache

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a problem in the storage gateway: the cache volume is full. When we look at the operating system there is still space available on that volume.

Based on the referenced aws model, only the files accessed regularly should be kept in the cache, but apparently it is keeping all the files, thus filling the cache and causing the requests of the users and applications to be made directly in aws. This causes slowness: it takes 2 minutes to open a 2 MB pdf file.

Our local storage is very large (4TB volume) and it is full, in addition to other smaller volumes that are also almost full.

How can I check if it is actually retaining only the recently used files or if it is retaining all the files?

And how could I perform the cache cleaning and start a new storage cycle in a safe way in order to avoid increasing the cache?

Comment: `letindon`? Or do you mean latency? Could you indicate whether the pdf file of 2MB opened sooner than 2 minutes when the cache was empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tryings, i was look for problem with implementation of solution and reads documentation of resource, and to my surprise that requirements are not attends.Só i   change that configurations mistakes and the storage gateway is flying.

The misconfiguration was about requirements, the minimo indicated by AWS is 16GB of memory, and at least 20% local storage used to cache  all data used loaded to AWS storage.

Comment: It would probably be a more valuable answer if you'd mention which was the wrong configuration and how you corrected it.

Comment: added misconfiguration.